# Cannot find symbol ActivityBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am facing a very strange problem. Everything was working fine before updating Android Studio. I was using version 4.1 but I found the update and updated IDE to version 4.2. Once the IDE is updated, the Android studio started showing lots of errors all of sudden. All the errors are related to Databinding. I am not able to figure it out yet although I have spent 2 days. For reference, you can see the attached logs.

[image]

Comment: In My case two things were there (Windows 10). 1) I deleted old settings folder `AndroidStudio4.1` from `AppData\Roaming\Google` on mac it might be different 2) Deleted the build folder & Restarted the IDE with `Invalidate cache/Restart`.

Comment: This did not work for me.